# Динамическое объединение ячеек таблицы с помощью php

Tags: php, html, table

Здравствуйте! Надо написать функцию, которая будет генерировать html-таблицу по заданным параметрам. На вход функции подается двумерный массив вида

```
  $style = array(
            array('cells' => '1,2,4,5)
            , array('cells' => '8,9')
   );
```

Здесь cells - это номера ячеек, которые нужно объединить в таблице. 
Таблица выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент, я написала код, который генерирует таблицу. Но я никак не могу понять, как сделать такое объединение.

```
function getTable($style){


$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$array_count = count($arr);

$table = '<table border="1"><tr>';

for ($i=0; $i < $array_count; $i++){

        if($i % 3 == 0 && $i  !=0 ){ 
            $table .= '</tr><tr>';
            }

    $table .= "<td>".$arr[$i]."</td>";
}


     $table .= "</tr></table>"; // close last row and table
     echo $table;
}

   getTable();
```

Comment: Зачем вам такой ужас и какого вида таблица? Всегда 3х3? Если нет то нужно как то получать ещё и максимум Х*Y блоков

Comment: Такое задание) Таблица всегда 3*3